# Strange behavior - Row won't reselect until three taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently facing a strange issue with a UITableView in iOS whereby deselected rows are no longer selectable immediately, you must tap three times before you can select again.  I'm implementing something akin to a checklist, with a "clear" button to go through and deselect all the cells. This effect only occurs when the cell had been previously selected, but the "clear" button is pressed. If a cell had been untouched before and is touched after the clear button, it will be presented and toggle fine.

Here is what I have

I should mention that the VC this Table is in is stored inside a container, hence the reference to it.

**The deselect**

```
- (IBAction)btnClearTapped:(id)sender {
    UITableView *locationList = self.locationsVc.tableView;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [locationList numberOfSections]; i++) {
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [locationList numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
            [locationList deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i] animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

**The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method**

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isChecked = !((NSNumber *) cellToggleDict[indexPath]).boolValue;
    cellToggleDict[indexPath] = @(isChecked);
    UIView *selectionColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    if (isChecked) {
        selectionColorView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        selectedLocations[indexPath] = [[Search sharedManager] locationAtIndexPath:indexPath];//PFObject
    }
    else {
        selectionColorView.backgroundColor = unselectedColor;
        [selectedLocations removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
    }
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColorView;
}
```

**And finally the dequeue and redraw method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Reuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *object = [[Search sharedManager] locationAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"Name"];
    BOOL isChecked = ((NSNumber *) cellToggleDict[indexPath]).boolValue;

    UIView *selectionColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    if (isChecked) {
        selectionColorView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
    }
    else {
        selectionColorView.backgroundColor = unselectedColor;
    }

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColorView;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't clear the `cellToggleDict` entries in the `btnClearTapped:` method.  You should have.

```
- (IBAction)btnClearTapped:(id)sender {
    UITableView *locationList = self.locationsVc.tableView;

    [cellToggleDict removeAllObjects];    // Clear all objects from the selected store

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [locationList numberOfSections]; i++) {
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [locationList numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
            [locationList deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i] animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer? While short answers may help by pointing in the right direction, it would be helpful to have further explanation.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks Paul. Makes sense too. Gonna clear everything out if I'm really going to clear it. Could you elaborate as to why it would work sometimes and not others?

Comment: My guess is it depends on which rows were selected before you cleared all and which rows you used to test afterwards.  BTW you can use an `NSIndexSet` rather than a dictionary to store the checked status